# real-time orientation tracker on vtk python

Tags: python, pyqt, vtk

I want to make a simple program using vtk and PyQt which can track and visualize orientation of IMU sensor such as Razor IMU 9 DOF sensor stick, only for the gyroscope sensor exactly in the real-time, so later the 3D object on vtk will rotate in 3-axis based on value from that sensor. my question is, how should I implement this on vtk and PyQt? I'm new on vtk and PyQt. it would be a honor from me if you can help me on this. thanks..